# Custom validation of ModelForm in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am working on a Django app to register sales. I have created three models: Project, Employee, and Sale.

The project and employee models are as follows:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 40)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Then the sale model:

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    sale_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    proactive_seller = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, related_name = 'proactive')

    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, related_name = 'participant')

    doers = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, related_name = 'doer')

    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sale_name
```

So the each sale object contains information on what project the sale is related to, which employee was the proactive/lead seller, which employees were participating in the sale, and also which employees will be doing the actual project.

In my forms.py I want to make sure that the sales are unique in the sense that I want to raise an error if the user is trying to enter a sale which already has the same project, same date and the same doers, i.e. the doers can't be allocated to the project more than once at a time.

My forms.py is currently looking like this:

```
class SaleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        widgets = {
        'start_date': DatePickerInput(), 
        'end_date': DatePickerInput(), 
    }
```

I tried the following:

```
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super.clean()
        start = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
        end = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
        doers = cleaned_data.get('doers')
        project = cleaned_data.get('project')
        if start and end and doers and project:
            queryset = Sale.objects.all()
            # Filter based on project
            q = queryset.filter(project__name=project, start_date = start, end_date = end)
            for employee in doers:
                q = q.filter(doers__name=employee)
            if q.count() > 1:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Sale has already been registered.')
```

However, the validation does not work as expected: I am still allowed to allocate “employees” to the same “project” at the same time (ie start date and end date).

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The clean method *does* apply to ModelForms, so it's not clear what your question is

Comment: Question edited for clarity

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do is validate every instance of the M2M relationship for a given instance. This can be fairly difficult to do. What should suffice is to filter down on sales with the same number of doers and filter out sales that contain a different doer on them.

```
from django.db.models import F, OuterRef, Exists, Q

q = queryset.filter(project__name=project, start_date=start, end_date = end)
other_doers = Employee.objects.filter(
     # Exclude any employee with the name of the doers on this project.
     # We only want other doers.
     ~Q(name__in=[e.name for e in doers]),
     # This links the subquery to the main query (Sale)
     doer=OuterRef('id'),
)
q = q.annotate(
    # Get the count of doers per sale
    doer_count=Count('doers__id', distinct=True),
    # Check if other doers are in the project
    has_other_doer=Exists(other_doers)
).filter(
    # Only look for sales with the same number of doers
    doer_count=len(doers),
    # Filter out sales that contain other doers
    has_other_doer=False,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @schillingt. I am not sure I am on board with your suggestion in terms of where the code goes and where the validation error should be raised. Does this go in forms.py, and when do I raise ValidationError?